# Namespace declaration not defined when running ng serve, but intellisense does pick it up

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I am working with the Azure Atlas library and decided to make my own typings for the third party library. I have defined a typings file `atlas.d.ts` in the project structure, which intellisense in VS Code does pick up and allow me to use the typings. The problem is, upon running `ng serve`, I get an error:

> ReferenceError: atlas is not defined

In the typings I simply declared a namespace as such:

```
declare namespace atlas {
    // ... Rest of the the interfaces and classes here
}
```

The issue is that I have read all the documentation on implementing global [namespaces or modules in typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) as well as read through a couple of stack overflow posts, modifying the `tsconfig` to take into account the `atlas.d.ts` file, even though the Angular-CLI ts config out of the box will already include all typings files, but no luck.

Any idea as to what could be causing `ng serve` to not take typings into account? You can find the repo I am working with [here](https://github.com/xavidram/AtlasTypingsIssue.git)

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the issue. I am not sure why this works but it does. The way I set up the project was, I would lazy load in the dependency resources into the project only when the Atlas Map needed to be rendered. As per the Azure Atlas documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-map-control). I need to have the  Azure Maps Script and Stylesheet in the Head of the index.html file for the project, which is what I was going to do dynamically when the map was needed. But in order to get the namespace to work, I manually added these two lines into the HEAD of my index.html file at the root of the project and now the atlas namespace I defined is recognized.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/css/atlas.min.css?api-version=1" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://atlas.microsoft.com/sdk/js/atlas.min.js?api-version=1"></script>
```

If anyone can give me some insight as to why this is the case? I am really interested as to why angular flipped on my own defined namespace and would not recognize it until I added the library that the typings would be registered for, even if they hadn't been needed yet.